# uib-accordion in angular for list display

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

My index page has two div's. In first < div > i extract names from $scope from controller mController. ng-repeat is used to iterate through the list to display Movies and Names in the first < div >. If a user selects any Name i use ng-model to send that object back to mController. In my second < div > i am trying to display cities ( child ) which belongs to Name ( parent ).

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="mController">
<h1>First Part fetch data from controller</h1>
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
      <uib-accordion-group  ng-repeat="x in names" ng-scroll="x in names">
         <uib-accordion-heading>
              {{ x.Movies }}
         </uib-accordion-heading>
      <div class> 
          <a ui-sref="iListPage" ng-repeat="a in x.Heros" ng-scroll="a in x.Heros" ng-model="a" ng-click="value.val=a"> {{ a.Name }} </a>
      </div>
    </uib-accordion-group>
  </uib-accordion>

<h1>Second Part using ui-router call iListPage </h1>
<div class>
  <div class="well">
      <div class="column-nav" ui-view="listColumn"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I have used ui-router to load iListPage in second div.
iListPage.html

```
<h3>iListPage ( work )</h3>
<div ng-controller="mController" >
        <div ng-repeat="x in value.val.Cities">
           {{x.Name}}
        </div>
</div>

<h3>iListPage ( Doesn't works )</h3>
<div>
    <uib-accordion ng-controller="mController">
        <uib-accordion-group close-others="true" ng-repeat="x in value.val.Cities">     
           {{x.Name}}
        </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('mController', function($scope){

$scope.value = {val:""};
$scope.names = [{ Json Object here }]

});
```

Image:

[image]

Not able to group cities list in uib-accordion. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<uib-accordion-group close-others="true" ng-repeat="x in value.val.Cities" heading="{{x.Name}}"></uib-accordion-group>` ?

Comment: That did the trick, but what if i don't want heading but display as content ?

Comment: Not sure I understand - It's an accordion, each group must have a heading and body. Your example worked - it showed the items of the accordion, but they were without a heading text

Comment: @AlonEitan: that's where i miss understood. I was trying to not to have header but display my data ( cities ) as body. or display cities in header without body.